# My java applet isn't appearing

Tags: java, loops, applet, draw

I don't know why but nothing is appearing?

I suppose to have a applet of a house.

```
import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.MouseAdapter;
import java.awt.event.MouseEvent;
import java.awt.event.*;


public class color extends JApplet
{
    public void init()
    {
        addMouseListener(new MyMouseListener());
        getContentPane().setBackground(Color.white);
    }
    public class MyMouseListener implements MouseListener
    {
    public void mouseClicked(MouseEvent e) 
    {
           int x = e.getX();
           int y = e.getY();
           boolean closeDoors = true;

           if(x>330 && x<280 && y>20 && y<20)
           {
               closeDoors = false;
               repaint();

           }

    }
    public void mouseEntered(MouseEvent e) { }
    public void mouseExited(MouseEvent e) { }
    public void mousePressed(MouseEvent e) { }
    public void mouseReleased(MouseEvent e) { }
    }
    public void paint ( Graphics g, boolean closeDoors)
           {
                super.paint (g);

                do
                {
               g.drawLine (35, 50, 570, 50);
                g.drawLine (35, 50, 250, 0);
                g.drawLine (250, 0, 570, 50);
                g.drawRect (50, 50, 500, 350);
                g.fillRect (100, 75, 80, 80);
                g.fillRect (400, 75, 80, 80);
                g.fillRect (240, 200, 125, 200);
                }
                 while (closeDoors = true);

                 if (closeDoors = false);
                {
                g.drawLine (35, 50, 570, 50);
                g.drawLine (35, 50, 250, 0);
                g.drawLine (250, 0, 570, 50);
                g.drawLine (180, 120, 100, 120);
                g.drawLine (400, 120, 480, 120);
                g.drawLine (140, 75, 140, 160);
                g.drawLine (450, 75, 450, 160);
                g.drawRect (50, 50, 500, 350);
                g.drawRect (100, 75, 80, 80);
                g.drawRect (400, 75, 80, 80);
                g.drawRect (240, 200, 125, 200);
                g.drawOval (330,280, 20, 20);
                }
            }
}
```

Comment: Did you make sure to compile your applet? If you did, please include the HTML applet/object/embed tag you used to show your applet in your question

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'll try to help get you on the right track :-)

You may already know this, but if your not using an IDE, I recommend using [appletviewer](http://download.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/tooldocs/windows/appletviewer.html) to develop your applets instead of with a browser. Just food for thought :-)

First of all, [Toader Mihai Claudiu](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5054815/my-java-applet-isnt-appearing/5054829#5054829)'s suggestion is correct. Change

```
            do
            {
           g.drawLine (35, 50, 570, 50);
            g.drawLine (35, 50, 250, 0);
            g.drawLine (250, 0, 570, 50);
            g.drawRect (50, 50, 500, 350);
            g.fillRect (100, 75, 80, 80);
            g.fillRect (400, 75, 80, 80);
            g.fillRect (240, 200, 125, 200);
            }
             while (closeDoors = true);

             if (closeDoors = false);
            {
```

into

```
            if (closeDoors)
            {
           g.drawLine (35, 50, 570, 50);
            g.drawLine (35, 50, 250, 0);
            g.drawLine (250, 0, 570, 50);
            g.drawRect (50, 50, 500, 350);
            g.fillRect (100, 75, 80, 80);
            g.fillRect (400, 75, 80, 80);
            g.fillRect (240, 200, 125, 200);
            }
            else
            {
```

Otherwise, you're going to be painting as long as closeDoors is true. You just need to paint once. Java will ask you to paint again when it has to (for instance, when you call repaint()).

Also, set `closeDoors` as a **member** variable. In other words, have:

```
public class color extends JApplet
{
  public boolean closeDoors = false;
```

And when you switch the value of closeDoors in the click listener, you can simplify it as:

```
       int x = e.getX();
       int y = e.getY();

       if(x>330 && x<280 && y>20 && y<20)
       {
           closeDoors = !closeDoors;
           repaint();

       }
```

That will, when you click in your specific area, invert the value of closeDoors. In other words, if `closeDoors` is `true`, it will be set to `false`, and vice versa.

Note, your code `if(x>330 && x<280 && y>20 && y<20)` probably won't work at all, since `y` cannot be greater than 20 and less than 20 at the same time, ever. I'll let you play with that to figure out what works :-).

Hope this helps.

---

Just a minor detail, but you should probably call your class `Color` instead of `color` to follow Java's [standard naming convention](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/codeconventions-135099.html#367), or call it something else if you don't want to clash with [java.awt.Color](http://download.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/awt/Color.html).

Comment: I get Applet not initializing

Comment: @user516805 How are you viewing your app? Is this through a web browser? You might want to include with your question your error message, along with your html applet (or object) tag.

Comment: @user516805 I don't know much about Eclipse; you'd probably have to look that up ([this](http://people.cs.uchicago.edu/~amr/121/labs/eclipsetute/applet.html) may help). If you are running this in a browser like firefox, ie, or chrome, what does it say besides "Applet not initializing" in the applet console?

Answer (score 3):

You are probably looping inside the `paint` method. It seems like an infinite loop there.

```
 do
 {
   g.drawLine (35, 50, 570, 50);
   g.drawLine (35, 50, 250, 0);
   g.drawLine (250, 0, 570, 50);
   g.drawRect (50, 50, 500, 350);
   g.fillRect (100, 75, 80, 80);
   g.fillRect (400, 75, 80, 80);
   g.fillRect (240, 200, 125, 200);
 } while (closeDoors = true);
```

I would replace this with:

```
 if (closeDoors = true)
 {
   g.drawLine (35, 50, 570, 50);
   g.drawLine (35, 50, 250, 0);
   g.drawLine (250, 0, 570, 50);
   g.drawRect (50, 50, 500, 350);
   g.fillRect (100, 75, 80, 80);
   g.fillRect (400, 75, 80, 80);
   g.fillRect (240, 200, 125, 200);
 }
```

Comment: Time to do some debugging then.  Use println statements throughout the program to tell you what it's doing.

Comment: I use some println statements. It works until I get to mouse clicked passage. I don't know what that means

Comment: @user516805 Try to Move the repaint outside of the if statement inside the mouseClicked method.

Answer (score 1):

Generally, in Swing you should never override the `paint()` method but instead `paintComponent`. (I'm not sure about JApplet, though - I would paint instead on a JPanel inside the applet, not the applet itself.)

And no endless loop in your paint-method - it should return quickly, not work eternally, as the Toader already said.

But this is not your problem, seemingly, as you wrote in a comment:

> I get Applet not initializing

Add such (important!) information to the question (it has an edit link for a reason, you know).

**Your browser should have a Java console somewhere, use it, and look whether there is some error message. Copy this (including the stacktrace, if any) to your question.** This could enable us helping you.

(If you are using OpenJDK with the icedTea-Plugin on Linux, look at `~/.icedteaplugin/java.stderr` and `~/.icedteaplugin/java.stdout` instead, they didn't yet implement the Java console.)

Comment: "Generally, in Swing you should never override the paint() method but instead paintComponent. (I'm not sure about JApplet, though - I would paint instead on a JPanel inside the applet, not the applet itself.)" -- This is correct.

Comment: I change my code and used paint Component but that still not working?>

Comment: I highlighted the important bit of my answer - take a look at the Java console, and copy the output to your question.

Answer (score 1):

One more problem. You are overloading not actually overriding `paint` (or `paintComponent`). Add `@Override` and the compiler will tell you of your mistake:

```
@Override public void paint(Graphics g, boolean closeDoors) { // wont compile
```

Seems like you need a course in debugging. At the very least put some `System.err.println`s in and check the Java Console.

Comment: when i type println under public void mouseClicked(MouseEvent e) i don't see in it console

Comment: `MouseListener`s are a bit odd. They bubble events up through the component tree, but stop when there's any listeners on a component. For a Swing `JApplet` (or `JFrame`), as opposed to a plain `Applet`, you would typically set a component as the content pane with all the stuff on it. It might work if you do `getContentPane().addMouseListener(...)`, but it'd be best to move you painting and listening to a different component (subclass `JComponent`, override `paintComponent`, `setOpaque`, set foreground and background colours, and add your listener, than `setContentPane` with that.

Comment: (Splitting you code from being dependent upon applet makes it cleaner and easier to test it in a `JFrame` without a browser (or fake browser). Removing stray dependencies is often a very good idea.)